# Php Uploader cannot be uploaded on xampp

Tags: php, html, xampp, uploader

I have just started to code in PHP and i have a problem with the code of the uploader: I use xampp and when I upload the file the result is

> File uploaded in C:xampp\htdocs\myfile.php

but the file does not exist.

Code Snippet below:

```html
<form action="sys.php" method="POST" ectype="multipart/form-data">
<c size=6>FILE TO UPLOAD</c><br>
<input type="file" name="sys"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" name="upload"><br><br>

<?php

   $path = "C:xampp\htdocs";

   if (isset($_POST["upload"])){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sys"]["tmp_name"], $path);
    echo "File Uploaded in $path\YOURFILE";

   }
   else{

    echo "[-]ERROR the uploader doesn't work";

   }
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `ectype="multipart/form-data"` a typo? Since it should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Note the `n` in `enctype`

Comment: You got a typo at `C:xamp\htdocs` should be `C:\xampp\htdocs` probably

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is <c> tag? I do not think it is standard html tag, does it come with some js framework or anything similar?

Comment: thanks you, but the program still doesn't work.

Comment: You should use the global FILES - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: You get any Error Message in the PHP Log file?

Comment: excuse the ignorance, but where it is located?

Answer (score 0):

change double quote to single and also set name for uploaded image.example code are  added below . Please put this inside `if (isset($_POST["upload"]))` condition

```
$path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\\'.$_FILES["sys"]["name"];
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not go

Comment: Did you changed form to     <form action="a.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: why a.php in <form action?

Comment: Its sys.php please change it to sys.php

Comment: <form action="sys.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<c size=6>FILE TO UPLOAD</c><br>
<input type="file" name="sys"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" name="upload"><br><br>

<?php


    

   if (isset($_POST["upload"])){
 $path = 'C:\xampp__\htdocs\\'.$_FILES["sys"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sys"]["tmp_name"], $path);
    echo "File Uploaded in $path\YOURFILE";

   }
   else{

    echo "[-]ERROR the uploader doesn't work";

   }
?>
</html>